# play games error You currently don't have the necessary rights to publish changes to this game.

Tags: android

**ERROR MESSAGE : You currently don't have the necessary rights to publish changes to this game. Please ask the owner of the 'Unknown Project' project to grant you access.**

So I published this game on 5th of august, i had implemented google play game services in the app.

APP LINK : https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.blinkgames.squareswipe

the google play game services worked fine, many people topped the leaaderboard for week, after a while the game services stopped working and in app with the error "Hmm,something went wrong in play games" I tried several solutions for weeks, nothing worked! I thought making a new leaderboard will help, but now i can not even publish the changes I make in the play game services.

I tried to contact google about this more than a few times, they seem to be helpless !

ERROR MESSAGES : 
link : https://i.stack.imgur.com/3SrPI.jpg

I am clueless about what to do next, this was my fist experience with Play Services

If anyone knows any solution to this, it would be much appreciated!!

Comment: "Hmm,something went wrong in play games"  When you get this message, you need to check the logcat to find out what is wrong.

Comment: I did, its not an error i got while debugging.
I had published the app with a working play services integrated to it.
after few days the play services stopped working.I did not change any code or uploaded any new .apk!

Comment: What do you do that causes this error? Does it happen while your app is running?

Comment: Have you solved it?

Comment: Have you solved problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a same kind of issue there are a message in the play console under services/publishing You currently don't have the necessary rights to unpublish this game. Please ask the owner of the 'Unknown Project' project to grant you access.

Also same kind of message under Game services/Game Detiles: You do not have permission to view the API console project. Contact an owner of the project to request permission.

Though I'm a owner of the project

Comment: what kind of answer is this?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue when I transferred my games from old account to new one, the services were still bound to the old account.

1. Log into your old account
2. Go to https://console.developers.google.com/iam-admin/iam
3. Click *Add* button and add your new account as owner.
4. Go back to google play console and you should have the appropriate permissions.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to delete your google play services data:

1. Firstly you’ll need to get into your devices settings menu, if you’re not sure how to do that checkout this tutorial How To Access The Android Settings Menu

2.Next you’ll see the settings menu, tap on the apps button. This will allow you to view and manage the apps installed on your device.

3.You should now see a list of all the apps installed on your device, scroll down till you find an app called Google Play Services, once you find it tap on it to open the settings menu for that app.

4.Now you will have a page with different options that you can modify for the Google Play Services app, we’ll need to tap on storage.

5.There should now be a page with some information about how much storage the app is using, along with two buttons, you’ll need to tap the button that’s labelled “Manage Space”

6.You will be taken to a page called “Google Play services storage” here you will need to tap on the button labelled “Clear all data” once you’ve cleared the data close Google Play Games and reopen it and the problem should be fixed

You could see this solution with images here: 
https://luketeachestech.com/hmm-something-went-wrong-play-games/

Maybe this help someone.